# Cannot find attachSchema property on Mongo.Collection with angular2-meteor

Tags: simple-schema, angular2-meteor

**Here is my problem :**

I want to use the power of simple-schema to be able to check my inserts against the following schema :

```
let UprocSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    "name": { type : String, label: "Nom Uproc" },
    "label": { type : String, label: "Libellé Uproc" },
    "status": { type : String, label: "Status UPR" }
});
```

For some reason I ignore, even if the SimpleSchema seems to be well instanciated, I cannot use the attachSchema property on Mongo.Collection.

**Here is my code :**

```
let repo_collection = new Mongo.Collection('repository');
export const Repository = new MongoObservable.Collection<Uproc>('repo_collection');
repo_collection.attachSchema( UprocSchema );
```

**Here is my error messages :**

> Property 'attachSchema' does not exist on type 'Collection<{}>'.
>
> TypeError: repo_collection.attachSchema is not a function

Comment: I think ```attachSchema``` is part of ```collection2``` package

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`attachSchema` is part of `[collection2][1]` package.

[Documentation](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#basic-usage) states:

> Create one or more SimpleSchema instances and then use them to
>   validate objects. **By adding the [aldeed:collection2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2) package to your
>   app, you can attach them to collections** to get automatic validation of
>   your insert and update operations.

Comment: the thing is that I cannot find any solution to install aldeed:collection2 on angular-meteor since there's no typings for this package, so I'm stuck with simple schema

Comment: Are you using any package for ```angular-meteor```? Also, is there any specific reason why you're attaching the schema to the collection? I believe it should work even withour that statement. The only change is that you must enforce the check schema on the server side as well.

Comment: I attach the schema to the collection because I want to be able to constraint the insert with unique value checking, and also to have auto-value inserts.